# phpinfo shows old mysql version after mysql upgrade (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, server, upgrade, php, mysql

I've upgraded MySql Server from version **5.5 to 5.7** on my Ubuntu 14.04 64bit version and everything is working fine, BUT: **phpinfo()** shows old mysql version 5.5.47, but **"mysql --version"** is showing version 5.7.12. The next strange attraction is that by checking version in simple php script:

```
printf("MySql CLIENT info: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
printf("MySql SERVER info: %s\n", mysql_get_server_info());
```

the output is also:

```
MySql CLIENT info: 5.5.47
MySql SERVER info: 5.7.12
```

and if I'm trying to install .deb package for mysql client version 5.7 from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=462071, Ubuntu software center just want to reinstall it again.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

doesn't help.

Anybody has a clue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What if you run `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`?

Comment: php5-mysq is in newst version!

Answer (score 2):

The `phpinfo()` function shows the version of the libmysqlclient.so library that's linked to mysql.so PHP extension.  You can check that by switching to `php5-mysqlnd` package that uses PHP MySQL native driver without linking to libmysqlclient.so.

You can confirm this by checking the version of libmysqlclient library on your system: `dpkg -l 'libmysqlclient*'` or generic version is here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libmysqlclient

As you can see, the version on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, that matches your MySQL Client version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the php configuration. For this disable the old php version and active the new by using following commands.

```
  sudo a2dismod php5.5
  sudo a2enmod php5.6
  sudo service apache2 restart
```